# Chinese Idiom puzzle 16 (中文填字遊戲)

Tags: idioms, games, puzzle

A new puzzle for March 2021

[image]

1. Steal the bell while covering your ears (deceiving yourself that you are deceiving the others)
2. Revenge one's personal vengeance in the name of official business
3. Opportunistic
4. Eating it means 'you are fired' (Cantonese custom)
5. Having the same aspirations and ideals
6. Superb craftsmanship
7. Received help but not return the favor
8. Match two parties together; act as a go-between
9. The castle gate is on fire (殃及池魚 上句)
10. If the water is too clean, there will be no fish (人至察則無徒  上句)
11. At old age that one's life is like a burning candle in the wind
12. Miserable wind and cold rain
13. Located at a high place looking down.(metaphorically in an advantageous position)
14. Like willow leaves swaying in the wind
15. No light is on  (a common phrase in Cantonese)
16. Arrogant; conceited
17. Stir things up; create chaos
18. there's always someone better
19. Very old and will die soon
20. Die alone at old age
21. Know right from wrong
22. People have different ideal and goal cannot work together
23. To act recklessly regardless of right and wrong.

A. The power of a united people's will is as strong as a castle.

B. Bully around

C. Find a better job elsewhere

D. There's honor among thieves

E. Fire spread by riding the wind

F. Building, constructing in large scale

G. Surrender

H. Turbulent, extremely unstable situation

I. Prime minister

J. Coincidence

K. No wind and the water is calm (a metaphor for everything is calm and normal)

L. Take by defrauding or seize by force. Mostly used to describe the unscrupulous seizure of property or power, etc.

M. cruel

N. Heaven doesn't give him more years (die too soon)

O. Oustanding

P. Social worker

Q. Ip Man's birthplace 南方武術之鄉

R. When the water rises, so do the boats (a metaphor for people or things rise in value or status due to change of situations)

S. Damn old fool (Common term in Cantonese)

T. Secretly give and receive in private

U. Metaphors of corrupted people have the same characteristics everywhere in the world.

V. Voice your objection when there's injustice

W. Know the fact but not reporting it to the authorities

X.  The night is dark and the wind is high

Y. Like fish in the water

Z. Confused; not knowing the truth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 掩耳盗铃
2. 公报私仇
3. 投机取巧
4. 无情鸡
5. 志同道合
6. 巧夺天工
7. 受恩不报
8. 撮合
9. 城门失火
10. 水至清则无鱼
11. 风烛残年
12. 凄风冷雨
13. 居高临下
14. 摇风摆柳
15. 乌灯黑火
16. 自高自大
17. 兴风作浪
18. 一山更比一山高
19. 行将就木
20. 孤独终老
21. 黑白分明
22. 道不同，不相为谋
23. 不分青红皂白

A. 众志成城

B. 横行霸道

C. 另谋高就

D. 盗亦有道

E. 火借风势

F. 大兴土木

G. 投降

H. 风雨飘摇

I. 丞相

J. 巧合

K. 风平浪静

L. 巧取豪夺

M. 残忍

N. 天不假年

O. 一枝独秀

P. 义工

Q. 佛山

R. 水涨船高

S. 老而不

T. 私相授受

U. 天下乌鸦一般黑

V. 不平则鸣

W. 知情不报

X. 月黑风高

Y. 如鱼得水

Z. 不明不白

Comment: Good job, the two minor mistakes are  (E): 火乘风势 and (P): 社工 As for (Z):不明不白, You already got 白 from 不分青紅皂白, so '不明 (? )白' is obviously '不明不白' and I believe you would catch it if you check your answers one more time